# how to test methods called by redux actions using jest

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

i am trying to write a unit test to test if the correct method is called when the action is dispatched. Here are my files:

actions.js

```
export const foo = () => ({type: 'fooAction'})
```

services.js

```
function* watchFoo(){
   yield takeEvery('fooAction', setFoo);
}
function setFoo() { console.log('foo'); }
```

And now in my spec file, i am test the action to see if setFoo is called.

**tests**/services.js

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
describe('test setFoo', () => {
   const mockStore = configureStore([]);
   const store = mockStore([]);
   store.dispatch(actions.foo());

   const storeActions = store.getActions();
   expect(storeActions).toEqual([action]); // this is true
})
```

When i try to debug setFoo, setFoo method is not called. I did set the spy to setFoo (removed that in the code above) which is not getting called. I also tried creating a mock for services and then spyOn the mocked service. Even then the setFoo is not called. To be clear, the issues are:

1. Why is my setFoo method not called?
2. How to write the unit test for this approach?

Comment: Services.js / `watchFoo()` does not look like it's integrated into your store in any way. I don't see why it would be called. If this test were to work, it would be testing redux-mock-store rather than your code.

Comment: In your test, don't use a mock store. Just test watchFoo directly.

Comment: @stone, the store is configured to add WatchFoo, i just didn't add here. Application is working absolutely fine. The questions are for testing.

Comment: @VinodKolla did you figure out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. We can't tell you why it's not working unless you post all the relevant code. Since you did not show any usage of `watchFoo` in your posted code, it's impossible to tell you why it's not working. Your question also does not mention what `takeEvery` is and how it's supposed to interact with your code. Are you using `redux-saga`?
2. Just test `watchFoo()` directly*.

The test you are writing is testing the integration of services.js with `redux-mock-store`, which is not a helpful test.

If you want an integration test that reflects your running code, you would need to test with the real store.

But you specifically mentioned a unit test, so you don't need a store at all.

*If you're using redux-saga, which you didn't mention, but I'm guessing that's where your `takeEvery` comes from, the recommended way to test is described here: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html. No mocking required.